# Slider ao clicar fique em Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, aplicação-web, slider

Olá galera estou montando um projeto web, e gostaria de saber sobre um slider que ao click fique em fullscreen, não estou encontrando uma boa opção.
Queria algo parecido com o do Site Tecmundo.

http://m.tecmundo.com.br/asus/12449-asus-eee-pad-slider-tem-precos-e-especificacoes-divulgadas.htm

Não conheço muitos plugins, a linguagem não interfere, jquery ou css3.

Obrigado!

Comment: basta procurar no google plugins jQuery essa [pagina](http://www.jssor.com/) possui vários modelos claro que vc terá que adaptar a seu gosto.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem alguns plugins que podem lhe ajudar

https://www.freshdesignweb.com/fullscreen-jquery-slider/